# How dictionary is created when making dictionary-based text classifications? How accuracy of values are determined?

Tags: classification, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to create sentimental analysis of about 1 million twits I've collected from Twitter. I've found a lot of dictionary related to text categorization. The dictionaries I found were rated words between -4 and +4. For example,

> fan 3
>
> angry -2
>
> revenge -2
>
> bad -3
>
> calm 2
>
> celebration 3

What I wonder is how numbers are given to words. How can I sure that numbers are valid? How dictionaries are created?

Comment: Hello Yunus, there are many ways to come up with this numbers. So, if you share the link from where you found those dictionaries, it might help to answer your question.

Comment: https://github.com/gokercebeci/sentiment-turkish/blob/master/build/AFINN-tr-165.txt

Answer (score 0):

## Source

The list you mentioned comes from:

> Finn Årup Nielsen, "A new ANEW: evaluation of a word list for
>   sentiment analysis in microblogs", Proceedings of the ESWC2011
>   Workshop on 'Making Sense of Microposts': Big things come in small
>   packages. Volume 718 in CEUR Workshop Proceedings: 93-98. 2011 May.
>   Matthew Rowe, Milan Stankovic, Aba-Sah Dadzie, Mariann Hardey
>   (editors)

Here is the link to the paper: http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/6006/pdf/imm6006.pdf

## Explanation

### The list of words

As explained in the paper, the words came from:

- Tweeter feeds related to the United Nation Climate Conference (COP15).
- Words from Original Balanced Affective Word List by Greg Siegle
- Internet slang found in Urban Dictionary
- Words from The Compass DeRose to Emotion Words by Steven J. DeRose

### Sentiment rating

Each word has a label in the range of $[-4,4]$, where $-4$ is the most **negative** and $4$ is the most **positive**.

The score was determined using [SentiStrength](http://sentistrength.wlv.ac.uk/).

From their website:

> SentiStrength estimates the strength of positive and negative
>   sentiment in short texts, even for informal language. It has
>   human-level accuracy for short social web texts in English, except
>   political texts. SentiStrength reports two sentiment strengths:
>
> -1 (not negative) to -5 (extremely negative)
>
> 1 (not positive) to 5 (extremely positive)
>
> Why does it use two scores? Because research from psychology has
>   revealed that we process positive and negative sentiment in parallel -
>   hence mixed emotions.
>
> SentiStrength can also report binary (positive/negative), trinary
>   (positive/negative/neutral) and single scale (-4 to +4) results.
>   SentiStrength was originally developed for English and optimised for
>   general short social web texts but can be configured for other
>   languages and contexts by changing its input files - some variants are
>   demonstrated below.

I couldn't figure out how they select the score (I believe it is because they sell the program and has proprietary rights). However, they claim to have *human-level accuracy* and provide a [list of papers](http://sentistrength.wlv.ac.uk/#About) that have evaluated the program.

You asked **How can I be sure that numbers are valid?** Sentiment on it self is quite subjective. Different people might rate words differently. However, the numbers work well in *most* cases (as shown by the results in the list of papers), so you could accept them as valid if your results seem reasonable.